# How can I manipulate key name in Object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, key, manipulate

I want to do change the name of a key in an `Object`. But when I want to do this with an if condition, I get this `(Assignment to function parameter 'key')` error. How can i manipulate a key name ?

**My Code:**

```
const personData = [];
Object.keys(testItem).forEach((key) => {
  item = testItem[key];
  if (key === 'Name'){
    key = 'Person Name';
  }
  personData.push({ name: key, data: Object.values(item) })
});
```

**testItem data:**

```
testItem = {Name: {...}, Surname: {...}}
```

I want the `Name` key to change to `Person Name` without error.

Comment: Can you add the data of `testItem`?

Comment: Your `item` variable should be declared with `const` or `let`. There's nothing wrong with assigning a value to a function parameter. That's not an error as far as JavaScript is concerned, so if something is complaining it's your IDE or a build tool (a "linter" checking your syntax).

Comment: Please see [How to avoid no-param-reassign when setting a property on a DOM object](/q/35637770/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

The `key` variable was taken in as input for the foreach function, and you shouldn't modify it - it is meant as a read only variable. An alternative that doesn't modify the `key` variable would be

```js
const personData = [];
Object.keys(testItem).forEach((key) => {
  let newKey = key;
  item = testItem[key];
  if (key === 'Name'){
    newKey = 'Person Name';
  }
  personData.push({ name: newKey, data: Object.values(item) })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you wanted to do, simply assign keys value to new key and delete previous one for example :

```
const personData = {
  Name: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
};


personData.PersonName = personData.Name
delete personData.Name;


console.log(personData.PersonName)
```